# How to display a specific window from an added parameter when clicking on a button?

Tags: javascript, solid-js

I am working on a solid-js application project. I would like to have in this application two buttons, a facebook button which opens a modal window containing information about facebook and a github button which opens a modal window containing information about github. So I created a `<Modal/>` component to create a modal window when called and wrote the following code:

```
<>
  <IconButton
    onClick={() => {
      setOpen(true)
      setName('facebook')
    }}
  >
    <ImFacebook class='h-6 w-6 text-blue-400' />
  </IconButton>

  <IconButton
    onClick={() => {
      setOpen(true)
      setName('Github')
    }}
  >
    <BsGithub class='h-6 w-6' />
  </IconButton>

  <Show when={name == 'facebook'}>
    <Modal
      onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
      open={open()}
      title='Facebook Users '
    >
      <div className='px-4' />
    </Modal>
  </Show>

  <Show when={name == 'Github'}>
    <Modal
      onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
      open={open()}
      title='Github Users '
    >
      <div className='px-4' />
    </Modal>
  </Show>
</>
```

Here is the expected behavior:

When the user clicks on the facebook or github button, the `name` attribute takes the `facebook` or `Github` value depending on which button was clicked. Then the computer displays a user-specific modal based on the value of the `name` attribute. But instead, when I test the app and click on a button be it facebook or Github button, no action is performed as a result and I don't understand why. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

In your case `name` is a signal accessor, not a data itself. To make `<Show />` work you need to write it this way

```
<Show when={name() == 'Github'}>
```

Or consider to use `<Switch />` https://www.solidjs.com/docs/latest/api#switchmatch instead of `<Show />`